# Закрытие потока в JAVA

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui

Есть GUI, при нажатии на кнопку запускается окно в отдельном потоке работающем 
в бесконечном цикле, после закрытия окна стоит ли удалять или останавливать поток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, если поток не "Демон". Обычные потоки продолжают свою работу даже после завершения основного потока. Если перед запуском потока указать `.setDeamon(true)` то при завершении главного потока, он завершит и поток-демон тоже, даже если он выполняется. **Вообщем процесс будет запущен пока хоть один из потоков выполняется, если только оставшиеся потоки не "демоны".**

Comment: Спасибо большое.